# using compiled regex in threads in perl

Tags: regex, multithreading, perl

In the code below I'm trying to create regular expressions which I want to use in multithreading.
The problem is that when using the regex, which is passed into the thread, it's compiled to 'Regexp=SCALAR(0x268aed0)' instead of '(?-xism:(testme))', and therefor the regex doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me why it is behaving this way?

I'm using perl v5.10.1.

```
#/usr/bin/perl

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

my @threads;
for ( 1..2 ) {
    push @threads, async {
        while ( defined( my $source = $q->dequeue() ) ) {
            my $text = "I want you to testme
            andmetoo please";
            my $re = $source->{regex};

            print "testing regex: " . $re . " for source $source->{id}\n";
            if ( $text =~ $re ) {
                 print "GOT IT: " . $1 . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

my @sources = (
    { 
        regex => qr/(testme)/,
        id => 's1'
    },
    { 
        regex => qr/(andmetoo)/,
        id => 's2'
    }
);

for ( @sources ) {
    print "adding source with regex $_->{regex} for source $_->{id}\n";
    $q->enqueue($_);
}

$q->enqueue(undef) for @threads;
$_->join() for @threads;
```

The output of code above is:

```
adding source with regex (?-xism:(testme)) for source s1
adding source with regex (?-xism:(andmetoo)) for source s2
testing regex: Regexp=SCALAR(0x268aed0) for source s1
testing regex: Regexp=SCALAR(0x268aee8) for source s2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your program, I get:

```
adding source with regex (?^:(testme)) for source s1
Unsupported ref type: REGEXP at a.pl line 37.
Perl exited with active threads:
        2 running and unjoined
        0 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached
```

Not surprisingly, compiled regular expressions can't be shared between threads. It seems your version of threads::shared didn't report this error.

---

The minimal test case is:

```
perl -Mthreads -Mthreads::shared -le'print shared_clone(qr/a/)'
```

Using a fresh Perl 5.10.1 install, the the above results in the following incorrect output:

```
Regexp=SCALAR(0xXXXXXXXX)
```

Never versions of thread::shared throw an error.

```
Unsupported ref type: REGEXP at -e line 1
```

---

The workaround is to pass a stringified version of the regex across.

```
$q->enqueue("$_");
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your code on 5.18, `Thread::Queue` 3.02, which calls in `threads::shared` 1.46, I get an error that `'REGEXP'` is an unsupported ref type. A little research told me that `threads::shared` does not allow regexps to be shared.  As you can see from the answser in this [bug report](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEEQFjAD&url=https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=57218&ei=ttr8UvnsAYaayQGW6oCgCw&usg=AFQjCNEVAaOjNpcpxhHgsDr966cCOazxHA&sig2=3yxfz9JLPqqmS2N2w8EO8g&bvm=bv.61190604,d.aWc&cad=rjt).

So you can share the string, and replace it with a compiled version *per* thread as a workaround. It appears that the answer is, you must compile each regex at least once per thread and cannot share compiled regex.